# Update a single key value in a Laravel Illuminate collection

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-5.5

I am building a collection from a Facebook API response.

```
$ads = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection;

if (!$ads->has($insight[$key])) {
    $ads->put($insight[$key], [
        'ad_id'                             => $insight[AdsInsightsFields::AD_ID],
        'ad_name'                           => $insight[AdsInsightsFields::AD_NAME],
        'ctr'                               => (float)$insight[AdsInsightsFields::CTR],
        'spend'                             => (float)$insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND],
    ]);
} else {
    // Increment spend value here.
}
```

If this were an array, I'd just do this:

```
$ads[$insight[$key]]['spend'] += $insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND];
```

How do I do that on a Collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I wrote macros capable of performing the updates needed.

```
// Set a single value by dot notation key.
Collection::macro('set', function ($key, $new) {
    $key = explode('.', $key);
    $primary_key = array_shift($key);
    $key = implode('.', $key);
    $current = $this->get($primary_key);

    if (!empty($key) && is_array($current)) {
        array_set($current, $key, $new);
    } else {
        $current = $new;
    }

    $this->put($primary_key, $current);
});
// Increment a single value by dot notation key.
Collection::macro('increment', function ($key, $amount) {
    $key = explode('.', $key);
    $primary_key = array_shift($key);
    $key = implode('.', $key);
    $current = $this->get($primary_key);

    if (!empty($key) && is_array($current)) {
        $new = array_get($current, $key, 0);
        $new += $amount;

        array_set($current, $key, $new);
    } else {
        $current += $amount;
    }

    $this->put($primary_key, $current);
});
// Decrement a single value by dot notation key.
Collection::macro('decrement', function ($key, $amount) {
    $key = explode('.', $key);
    $primary_key = array_shift($key);
    $key = implode('.', $key);
    $current = $this->get($primary_key);

    if (!empty($key) && is_array($current)) {
        $new = array_get($current, $key, 0);
        $new -= $amount;

        array_set($current, $key, $new);
    } else {
        $current -= $amount;
    }

    $this->put($primary_key, $current);
});
```

With this, all I need to do is something like:

```
$ads->increment($insight[$key] . '.spend', $insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND]);
```

If I want to simply set a value, whether the key exists or not, I can do this:

```
$ads->set($insight[$key] . '.spend', $insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND]);
```

Comment: the `increment()` function is for "Eloquent Collections' not for 'Collections'. that means it directly updates database columns. don't use it unless you want directly update the database column there.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan this is a collection of type `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` not `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` so that method I created with the macro does not already exist.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry, I didn't see that It's custom created.

Comment: In your `set` macro,  `collect(['x' => ['y','z'])->set('x.0', 'A');` wouldn't work since you test for `!empty($key)`. Better would be to convert the int to string and check for length `strlen(trim((string) $key))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ads->{$insight[$key]}['spend'] +=  $insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND];
```

It's a little weird looking but you need to access the first part as an object property `->propertyName`, that property name you're grabbing from an array `$insight[$key]` so you need to throw brackets around it, finally you need to ask for an array key of that property with `[spend]` at the end.

Comment: `$ads->{$insight[$key]}` always throws the error `Property does not exist on this collection instance.` even after running the `put()` portion.

Comment: odd, try a dd($insight[$key], $ads); and check that the first value dumped exists as a key in the collection dumped

Comment: Yep, it exists. Created a very simple test scenario to make sure the code would work but no bueno: `$ads = new Collection(); $key = 'test'; $ads->put($key, ['spend' => 0]); $ads->{$key}['spend'] += 5;`

Comment: sorry, not sure where to go from here, I use that syntax in my own project with no problems

Answer (score 0):

first thing, this is a collection of arrays (not a collection of collection).

your question was how to get a particular key value pair in a collection,

**The Answer is 'get()' function on collection.**
now you can simply increment the 'spend' value as below.

```
$ads->get($insight[$key])['spend'] += $insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND];
```

**NOTE**

if you need whole thing to be collections, Update your code to make a collection of collection as below

```
$ads->put($insight[$key],  collection([
    'add_id'                            => $insight[AdsInsightsFields::AD_ID],
    'ad_name'                           => $insight[AdsInsightsFields::AD_NAME],
    'ctr'                               => (float)$insight[AdsInsightsFields::CTR],
    'spend'                             => (float)$insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND],
]);
```

then you can increment spend value as below.

```
$ads->get($insight[$key])->spend += $insight[AdsInsightsFields::SPEND];
```

Comment: `$ads->get($insight[$key])['spend']` will not work because `get()` does not return by reference so the property is never updated.

Comment: `get()` function returns by reference,  but ['spend'] was the problem here. I apologize for that. That's why i suggest you the second way, make everything collections instead of keeping arrays. `$ads->get($insight[$key])->spend += $insight[AdsInsigntsFields::SPEND];' works fine